# VBA-Excel: Read Data from XML File

Tags: excel, vba

I have following XML data which is coming from REST call ,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <result>
        <cs>1</cs>                             
        <cs>2</cs>
        <cs>3</cs>
        <cs>4</cs>
    </result>
    <result>
        <br>A</br>                             
        <br>B</br>
    </result>
</response>
```

I want to read this data in excel as,
[Excel Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbanA.png)

and here the length of cs and br tag is not fixed it will be different for every data.

Comment: great, what have you tried so far, any code?

Comment: Dim objHTTP As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Dim Resp As New DOMDocument
Dim Result As IXMLDOMNode

URL = https://example.abc.com
objHTTP.Open "get", URL, False
objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
' Authorization Code
objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", AuthorizationCode
objHTTP.Send
'giving 200
Debug.Print objHTTP.Status 
'giving xml
Debug.Print objHTTP.ResponseText

Resp.LoadXML objHTTP.ResponseText

Comment: @S.R.KHAN why don't you post your code as an answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you. Note that I haven't bother with formatting each of the cells:
First do this
Click Tools > References.  Check these libraries
- Microsoft WinHttp Services, version 5.1
- Microsoft xml v6.0

```
 Sub TestXML()
    URL = "https://example.abc.com" 'Your URL
    AuthorizationCode = "Basic <Password>" 'Please put only encrypted password

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim objHTTP As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Dim jsonString As String
    Dim Resp As New DOMDocument
    Dim Result As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    objHTTP.Open "get", URL, False
    objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
    objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
    objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", AuthorizationCode
    objHTTP.Send

    Debug.Print objHTTP.Status
    Debug.Print objHTTP.ResponseText

    Set ws = Sheets("sheet1")
    ws.Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Cells.Clear
    Resp.LoadXML objHTTP.ResponseText
    Set lists = Resp.DocumentElement

    x = 2
    y = 1
    For Each listNode In lists.ChildNodes
        x = 2
        Cells(1, y).Value = lists.ChildNodes(y - 1).ChildNodes(0).BaseName
        For Each fieldNode In listNode.ChildNodes
            Cells(x, y).Value = fieldNode.Text
            x = x + 1
        Next fieldNode
        y = y + 1
    Next listNode
End Sub
```

Comment: 'This is my sample code
Dim objHTTP As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Dim Resp As New DOMDocument
Dim Result As IXMLDOMNode

URL = https://example.abc.com
objHTTP.Open "get", URL, False
objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
' Authorization Code
objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", AuthorizationCode
objHTTP.Send
'giving 200
Debug.Print objHTTP.Status 
'giving xml
Debug.Print objHTTP.ResponseText

Resp.LoadXML objHTTP.ResponseText

Comment: Your code is giving error "Error 91" for line "For Each listNode In lists.ChildNodes"

Comment: Since you've updated the data you don't need the sub call that converts #s to letters - so I've deleted it.  It works for me using Office 365 ProPlus v 15.   All I can suggest is that you copy the code and your xml file into a new question and maybe someone else will know.

Comment: Thank you friend, I got output and I am sharing it please paste it I will mark it as the answer because I got it from your code.

Comment: It should allow you to - I've pasted reams of code before.

Comment: Just approved it.